# Woocommerce show user password on order details page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce on Order Details page we have special box to set user password (user is generated automatically on thank you page - just PayPal doesn't work for some reason) - in the picture. This password is acutally access code (nothing too much personal) but I'm trying to make it little bit more useful for customer support.

I want to show current password for this user (which was manually entered by person) below this input field. Because many times someone from logistics forgot to set password/access code and it will be really helpful if current code is visible below this box. Is this even possible because passwords are hashed? I'm using code below for that functionality

```
// Adding a custom Metabox on WooCommerce single orders (on right side)
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_shop_order_metabox' );
function add_custom_shop_order_metabox(){
global $post;

$customer_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_customer_user', true );

if ( $customer_id > 0 ) {
    add_meta_box(
        'custom_shop_order_metabox',
        __('Access Code', 'woocommerce'),
        'content_custom_shop_order_metabox',
        'shop_order',
        'side',
        'core'
    );
}
}

// Custom Metabox content on WooCommerce single orders
function content_custom_shop_order_metabox() {
global $post;

$customer_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_customer_user', true );

echo '<div class="options_group edit_password" style="min-height:4.5em;margin-top:12px;;">
    <input type="text" name="customer-password" class="customer-password" value="">
    <a class="button submit-password" style="text-align:center;">' . __('Submit', 'woocommerce') . '</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="customer-id" class="customer-id" value="' . $customer_id . '">
    <div class="message-response" style="margin-top:6px;"></div>
</div>';
}

// Jquery Ajax
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'edit_password_orders_column_js' );
function edit_password_orders_column_js() {
global $pagenow, $post_type;

if ( 'post.php' === $pagenow && 'shop_order' === $post_type ) :
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( function($){
    $('div.edit_password > .message-response').fadeOut(0);
    $('div.edit_password > .button.submit-password').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        var $this = $(this),
            $parent = $this.parent(),
            password = $parent.find('.customer-password').val(),
            user_id  = $parent.find('.customer-id').val(),
            text = '',
            color = 'red';

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('/admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
            data: {
                'action'           : 'updating_customer_password',
                'customer-password': password,
                'customer-id'      : user_id
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if ( response === 'empty' ) {
                    text  = '<?php echo __('Empty input, retry…', 'woocommerce'); ?>';
                } else if ( response === 'whitespace' ) {
                    text  = '<?php echo __('No white spaces…', 'woocommerce'); ?>';
                } else {
                    text  = '<?php echo __('Password Updated!', 'woocommerce'); ?>';
                    color = 'green';
                }
                $parent.find('.customer-password').val('');
                $parent.find('.message-response').html('<small>'+text+'<small>').css('color',color).fadeIn();
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $parent.find('.message-response').fadeOut( function(){ $(this).css('color','black').html(''); });
                }, 2000)
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<?php
endif;
}

// PHP Ajax receiver

add_action('wp_ajax_updating_customer_password', 
'action_ajax_updating_customer_password');
function action_ajax_updating_customer_password() {
if ( isset($_POST['customer-password']) && isset($_POST['customer-id']) ) {
    $password = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['customer-password'] );
    $user_id  = intval( esc_attr( $_POST['customer-id'] ) );

    if ( ! $password ) {
        echo 'empty'; // empty input
    } elseif ( strpos($password, ' ') !== false ) {
        echo 'whitespace'; // empty input
    } else {
        wp_set_password( $password, $user_id ); // Set new password
    }
    wp_die();
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to store the password(plain text posted) as usermeta before hashing to display as plain text.

Comment: Huh sounds complicated for nom-programmer. Will try to find more info about this. Thanks

Comment: Whatever you do, don't store the password as a plain text. Can you go 2 steps back and describe the real issue? There must be a better solution than showing the password on the website

Comment: _"Because many times someone from logistics forgot to set password/access code"_ - just conveying _that_ information does not require to display the actual value, a "Is access code set? Yes/No" display should do.

Comment: We're using Wordpress User system for totally different approach, to be honest this access code doesn't hide something special and it's set by our side, not from user side. This is used just to confirming that user got an mail letter (physical) and many times customers call our customer support and they need to tell this code but our CS doesn't have this code displayed on order so they need to set it again because we don't know if it's set or not. So nothing special about this "password".

Comment: I’m thinking if is possible to make another field which captures what is pasted in first input field and then save second field somewhere. Is that possible?